# Zipping strings together at arbitrary index and step (Python)

Tags: string, python-2.7

I am working in Python 2.7. I am trying to create a function which can zip a string into a larger string starting at an arbitrary index and with an arbitrary step.

For example, I may want to zip the string `@#*#*` into the larger string `TNAXHAXMKQWGZESEJFPYDMYP` starting at the 5<sup>th</sup> character with a step of 3. The resulting string should be:

```
TNAXHAX@MK#QW*GZ#ES*EJFPYDMYP
```

The working function that I came up with is

```
#Insert one character of string every nth position starting after ith position of text

text="TNAXHAXMKQWGZESEJFPYDMYP"

def zip_in(string,text,i,n):
    text=list(text)
    for c in string:
        text.insert(i+n-1,c)
        i +=n
    text = ''.join(text)
    print text
```

This function produces the desired result, but I feel that it is not as elegant as it could be.

Further, I would like it to be general enough that I can zip in a string backwards, that is, starting at the i<sup>th</sup> position of the text, I would like to insert the string in one character at a time with a backwards step.

For example, I may want to zip the string `@#*#*` into the larger string `TNAXHAXMKQWGZESEJFPYDMYP` starting at the 22<sup>nd</sup> position with a step of -3. The resulting string should be:

```
TNAXHAXMKQW*GZ#ES*EJ#FP@YDMYP
```

With my current function, I can do this by setting *n* negative, but if I want a step of -3, I need to set *n* as -2.

All of this leads me to my question:

**Is there a more elegant (or Pythonic) way to achieve my end?**

---

Here are some related questions which don't provide a general answer:

[Pythonic way to insert every 2 elements in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258573/pythonic-way-to-insert-every-2-elements-in-a-string)
[Insert element in Python list after every nth element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040525/insert-element-in-python-list-after-every-nth-element)
[Merge Two strings Together at N & X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845436/merge-two-strings-together-at-n-x)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some functions from the `itertools` and `more_itertools` libraries (make sure to have them) and combine them to get your result : [`chunked`](http://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) and [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

```
# Parameters
s1 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ' # your string
s2 = '@#@#' # your string of elements to add
int_from = 4 # position from which we start adding letters
step = 2 # we will add in elements of s2 each 2 letters

return_list = list(s1)[:int_from] # keep the first int_from elements unchanged
for letter, char in izip_longest(chunked(list(s1)[int_from:], step), s2, fillvalue=''):
    return_list.extend(letter)
    return_list.append(char)
```

Then get your string back by doing :

```
''.join(return_list)
```

Output :

```
# For the parameters above the output is :
>> 'ABCDEF@GH#IJ@KL#MNOPQ'
```

---

*What does `izip_longest(chunked(list(s1)[int_from:], step), s2, fillvalue='')` return ?*:

```
for letter, char in izip_longest(chunked(list(s1)[int_from:], step), s2, fillvalue=''):
    print(letter, char)

>> Output
>> (['E', 'F'], '@')
   (['G', 'H'], '#')
   (['I', 'J'], '@')
   (['K', 'L'], '#')
   (['M', 'N'], '')
   (['O', 'P'], '')
   (['Q'], '')
```